# Editing Google Calendar Event Meets URI With External Link via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've had code that has been working for the last year or so, that adds a new Google Meets Entry Point with my own custom URI to the Google Calendar Event via the Google Calendar API.

For example if I click on "Join with Google Meet" below it does not go to a `meets.google.com` link like usual, because I replaced it with my own custom link.
[image]

Unfortunately for some reason in the past couple weeks this stopped working. Now when my code tries to edit the URI for the meet, it returns this error: `Google::Apis::ClientError (invalid: Invalid Value)`. I haven't changed the code in months and this only started happening recently.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
def update_event_meet_url(service, event, send_updates = "all")
    entry_points = [
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EntryPoint.new(
        entry_point_type: "video",
        label: meeting_url,
        uri: meeting_url,
      ),
    ]

    if original_phone_info.present?
      entry_points << Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EntryPoint.new(
        entry_point_type: original_phone_info["entry_point_type"],
        label: original_phone_info["label"],
        uri: original_phone_info["uri"],
        pin: original_phone_info["pin"],
        region_code: original_phone_info["region_code"],
      )
    end

    event_changes = {
      conference_data: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::ConferenceData.new(entry_points: entry_points),
    }

    updated_event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(event_changes)

    service.patch_event(
      gcalendar_id,
      event.id,
      updated_event,
      conference_data_version: 1,
      send_updates: send_updates,
    )
  end
```

I know the problem is with the video entry point because I replaced the `meeting_url` with a working `https://meets.google.com` link and it worked. But if I try anything else that is not `meets.google.com` it errors.

I'm using this Ruby gem https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that the issue is creating / updating the event with an external video conferencing tool? Have you tried with the [Try this section on Events:Update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that I can't patch the event with an external video link. It has to be `meet.google.com`. But this is weird because it has been working for the last year or so and has only recently started returning this error. I have tried with the `Try this section` already and it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted google support and looks like there was a recent release that changed the behavior of `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type`. More info here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/releases#january_11_2021)we

Basically I needed to change my conference solution key type to `addOn` instead of `hangoutsMeet`. The subsequent problem I had was that I still needed a hangoutsMeet link, since the third party url I'm using would eventually redirect to the meets.google.com link. And the only way to get a `hangoutsMeet` link is to create the initial event with `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type = hangoutsMeet`.

So what I did was create the google event with `conferenceData.conferenceSolution.key.type = 'hangoutsMeet'` and then I did a subsequent `patch_event` call that set the initial hangoutsMeet conference solution to `null` and created a new `conferenceSolution` of type `addOn`. That way I could store the original meets.google.com link and then use that link for the redirect from my third party link.

```
def update_event_meet_url(service, event, send_updates = "all")
    entry_points = [
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EntryPoint.new(
        entry_point_type: "video",
        label: meeting_url,
        uri: meeting_url,
      ),
    ]

    conference_solution_key = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::ConferenceSolutionKey.new(type: "addOn")
    conference_solution =
      Google::Apis::CalendarV3::ConferenceSolution.new(key: conference_solution_key)
    event_changes = {
      conference_data: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::ConferenceData.new(
        conference_solution: conference_solution,
        entry_points: entry_points,
        create_request: nil,
      ),
    }

    updated_event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(event_changes)

    service.patch_event(
      gcalendar_id,
      event.id,
      updated_event,
      conference_data_version: 1,
      send_updates: send_updates,
    )
end
```